# How can I remove POS tags before slashes in nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

This is part of my project where I need to represent the output after phrase detection like this - (a,x,b) where a, x, b are phrases. I constructed the code and got the output like this:

```
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Tom/NNP) (VP is/VBZ) (NP in/IN Kolkata/NNP))
```

I want to make it just like the previous representation which means I have to remove 'CLAUSE', 'NP', 'VP', 'VBD', 'NNP' etc tags.

How to do that?

### What I tried

First wrote this in a text file, tokenize and used `list.remove('word')`. But that is not at all helpful.
I am clarifying a bit more.

### My Input

`(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))`

### Output will be

[Jack,loved,Peter], [Jack,stayed,in London] 
The output is just according to the braces and without the tags.

Comment: Please share the related part of your code

Comment: Which part of the code do you want basically? Anyway Text=open('phrase_output.txt')
t=Text.read()

text=nltk.word_tokenize(t);
print text
text.remove('CLAUSE')
text.remove('NP')

Comment: strange because `nltk.word_tokenize(t); ` gives me a list of words, no tags :  `['Julia', 'loves', 'Peter']` ...are you using some different configuration or something?

Comment: what was you input? Is it 'Julia loves Peter'?

Comment: yes `'Julia loves Peter'`

Comment: My input was '(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))'.

Comment: This is a parsing problem not nltk problem

Comment: @SoubhikR BTW, how did you extract the clause?

Comment: @bigOTHER can you suggest specifically?

Comment: I think @alvas gave you a good answer

Comment: Can you edit your question and add *exactly* what you want to see as the cleaned-up version of your three sentences? You think you're clear, but you're not.

Comment: @alexis Thanks for comment. I made some improvements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged this `nltk`, let's use the NLTK's tree parser to process your trees. We'll read in each tree, then simply print out the leaves. Done.

```
>>> text ="(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))"
>>> tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(text, read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
>>> print(tree.leaves())

['Jack', 'stayed', 'in', 'London']
```

The lambda form splits each `word/tag` pair and discards the tag, keeping just the word.

#### Multiple trees

I know, you're going to ask me how to process a whole file's worth of such trees, and some of them take more than one line. That's the job of the NLTK's `BracketParseCorpusReader`, but it expects terminals to be in the form `(POS word)` instead of `word/POS`. I won't bother doing it that way, since it's even easier to trick `Tree.fromstring()` into reading all your trees as if they're branches of a single tree:

```
allmytext = """
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Tom/NNP) (VP is/VBZ) (NP in/IN Kolkata/NNP))
"""
wrapped = "(ROOT "+ allmytext + " )"  # Add a "root" node at the top
trees = nltk.Tree.fromstring(wrapped, read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
for tree in trees:
    print(tree.leaves())
```

As you see, the only difference is we added `"(ROOT "` and `" )"` around the file contents, and used a for-loop to generate the output. The loop gives us the children of the top node, i.e. the actual trees.

Comment: Thank you @alexis. This stuff is helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. When you see an answer that solves your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark next to it. (You can also upvote any and all answers you found useful).

Comment: I think I don't have to do this because '(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))' is  a tree. show just tree.leaves() and boom!

Comment: If you have a way to split up your input into single-tree clauses, then you don't.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> clause = "(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))"
>>> pattern = r'\w+:?(?=\/)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, clause)
['Jack', 'loved', 'Peter']
```

---

## EDITED

For multiple clauses:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'\w+:?(?=\/)'
>>> clauses = """(CLAUSE (NP school/NN) (VP is/VBZ situated/VBN) (NP in/IN London/NNP)) (CLAUSE (NP The/DT color/NN of/IN the/DT sky/NN) (VP is/VBZ) (NP pink/NN))"""
>>> [re.findall(pattern, clause) for clause in clauses.split(' (CLAUSE ')]
[['school', 'is', 'situated', 'in', 'London'], ['The', 'color', 'of', 'the', 'sky', 'is', 'pink']]
```

If clauses are separated by newline:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'\w+:?(?=\/)'
>>> clauses = """(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))
... (CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))
... (CLAUSE (NP Tom/NNP) (VP is/VBZ) (NP in/IN Kolkata/NNP))"""
>>> [re.findall(pattern, clause) for clause in clauses.split('\n')]
[['Jack', 'loved', 'Peter'], ['Jack', 'stayed', 'in', 'London'], ['Tom', 'is', 'in', 'Kolkata']]
```

To join the output into a string:

```
>>> " ".join(['Jack', 'loved', 'Peter'])
'Jack loved Peter'

>>> clauses = [['Jack', 'loved', 'Peter'], ['Jack', 'stayed', 'in', 'London'], ['Tom', 'is', 'in', 'Kolkata']]
>>> [" ".join(cl) for cl in clauses]
['Jack loved Peter', 'Jack stayed in London', 'Tom is in Kolkata']
```

Comment: my objective is to identify the phrase, not the words and if you take more than one sentence your code will generate undesired output. One solution could be to keep the braces. You take this as input and modify your code : `(CLAUSE (NP school/NN) (VP is/VBZ situated/VBN) (NP in/IN London/NNP)) (CLAUSE (NP The/DT color/NN of/IN the/DT sky/NN) (VP is/VBZ) (NP pink/NN))` @alvas

Comment: perhaps I was not much clear. Actually you can well understand that what I did  is completely based on phrases. Now what I want to discriminate them by commas and braces so that we can use them easily in different aspects e,g associative rule mining , text processing etc. Now I edited the question. I think now the aim is quite clear to you. Thanks for your effort, @alvas

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying something like this:

```
import re
tmp = '(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))'

tmp = re.split(r'[()/ ]', tmp)
#Use 're.split()' to split by character that was not a letter.
>>> ['', 'CLAUSE', '', 'NP', 'Jack', 'NNP', '', '', 'VP', 'loved', 'VBD', '', '', 'NP', 'Peter', 'NNP', '', '']

result = (tmp[4], tmp[9], tmp[14])
>>> ('Jack', 'loved', 'Peter')
```

Is this what you want?

**EDIT:**

I should thought it through:(.

```
import re
tmp = '(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))'

tmp = re.sub(r'[()]', '', tmp)
>>> 'CLAUSE NP Jack/NNP VP loved/VBD NP Peter/NNP'
result = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]*/', tmp)
>>> ['Jack/', 'loved/', 'Peter/']
＃Now create a generator.
gen = (i[:-1] for i in result)
tuple(gen)
>>> ('Jack', 'loved', 'Peter')
```

Comment: result = (tmp[4], tmp[9], tmp[14]), For a large number of data how can you find the positions?

Comment: @SoubhikR I should thought it through:(.

Comment: (CLAUSE
  (NP school/NN)
  (VP is/VBZ situated/VBN)
  (NP in/IN London/NNP))
(CLAUSE
  (NP The/DT color/NN of/IN the/DT sky/NN)
  (VP is/VBZ)
  (NP pink/NN))

Comment: Keep the braces. Otherwise can't able to discriminate multiple lines. Anyway great work, man.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate your comment, it get me back to the right track.:)

Comment: You deserve that @SimonShyu. But still there is a necessity to fix it. Have you tried it for multiline? You can try it for " (CLAUSE (NP school/NN) (VP is/VBZ situated/VBN) (NP in/IN London/NNP)) (CLAUSE (NP The/DT color/NN of/IN the/DT sky/NN) (VP is/VBZ) (NP pink/NN))" this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

When the outputs are these:
`(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP loved/VBD) (NP Peter/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Jack/NNP) (VP stayed/VBD) (NP in/IN London/NNP))
(CLAUSE (NP Tom/NNP) (VP is/VBZ) (NP in/IN Kolkata/NNP))`
It is quite obvious that they are tree. So just use Tree.leaves().
Here is the full code:

```
def leaves(self):
    """
    Return the leaves of the tree.

        >>> t = Tree.fromstring("(S (NP (D the) (N dog)) (VP (V chased) (NP (D the) (N cat))))")
        >>> t.leaves()
        ['the', 'dog', 'chased', 'the', 'cat']

    :return: a list containing this tree's leaves.
        The order reflects the order of the
        leaves in the tree's hierarchical structure.
    :rtype: list
    """
    leaves = []
    for child in self:
        if isinstance(child, Tree):
            leaves.extend(child.leaves())
        else:
            leaves.append(child)
    return leaves
```

You can find it from here: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html