# NLTK - Remove Tags From Parsed Chunks

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import nltk
import re

from nltk.tree import *
from nltk.chunk.util import tagstr2tree
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

text = "Yarın, Mehmet ile birlikte Ankara'da ki Nüfus Müdürlüğü'ne, Aziz 
Yıldırım ile birlikte, Şükrü Saraçoğlu Stadı'na gideceğiz.".decode("utf-8")

tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
tagged_text2 = word_tokenize(text)

grammar = "NP:{<NNP>+}"

cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(tagged_text)

for tree in result:
    print(tree)

wrapped = "(ROOT "+ str(result) + " )"  # Add a "root" node at the top
trees = nltk.Tree.fromstring(wrapped, read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0])

for tree in trees:
    print(tree.leaves())

for tree2 in result:
    print(nltk.Tree.fromstring(str(tree2), read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0]))
```

The Output:

```
(NP Yar\u0131n/NNP)
(u',', ',')
(NP Mehmet/NNP)
(u'ile', 'NN')
(u'birlikte', 'NN')
(NP Ankara'da/NNP ki/NNP Nufus/NNP Mudurlugu'ne/NNP)
(u',', ',')
(NP Aziz/NNP Y\u0131ld\u0131r\u0131m/NNP)
(u'ile', 'NN')
(u'birlikte', 'NN')
(u',', ',')
(NP Sukru/NNP Saracoglu/NNP Stad\u0131'na/NNP)
(u'gidece\u011fiz', 'NN')
(u'.', '.')


['Yar\\u0131n', ',', 'Mehmet', 'ile', 'birlikte', "Ankara'da", 'ki', 'Nufus', "Mudurlugu'ne", ',', 'Aziz', 'Y\\u0131ld\\u0131r\\u0131m', 'ile', 'birlikte', ',', 'Sukru', 'Saracoglu', "Stad\\u0131'na", 'gidecegiz', '.']


(NP Yar\u0131n)
(u',', ',')
(NP Mehmet)
(u'ile', 'NN')
(u'birlikte', 'NN')
(NP Ankara'da ki Nufus Mudurlugu'ne)
(u',', ',')
(NP Aziz Y\u0131ld\u0131r\u0131m)
(u'ile', 'NN')
(u'birlikte', 'NN')
(u',', ',')
(NP Sukru Saracoglu Stad\u0131'na)
(u'gidece\u011fiz', 'NN')
(u'.', '.')
```

I referenced from :[How can I remove POS tags before slashes in nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705555/how-can-i-remove-pos-tags-before-slashes-in-nltk)

I want to grouping proper names and remove the tags but when i used the solution it effects the whole text and after that my chunk parse is gone. I really tried the understand the tree structure but how can i apply the the removing function in for statement. I want my Output like:

**My desired output:**

```
[Yar\u0131n]
[,]
[Mehmet]
[ile]
[birlikte]
[Ankara'da ki Nufus Mudurlugu'ne]
...
...
```

Also i can't deal with utf-8 as you see my output is full of non-ascii characters. How can i deal with it ?

**EDIT:**

```
for i in range(len(tree)):
    arr.append(nltk.Tree.fromstring(str(tree[i]), read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0]).leaves())
    print(arr[i])
```

I found what shoul i write in the code but now i have the following error. I think i can't append punctuations on my array.

```
['Yar\\u0131n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./chunk2.py", line 61, in <module>
    arr.append(nltk.Tree.fromstring(str(tree[i]), read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0]).leaves())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 630, in fromstring
    cls._parse_error(s, match, open_b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 675, in _parse_error
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Tree.read(): expected u'(' but got ','
            at index 0.
                ","
                 ^
```

Comment: try `text = u"Yarın, Mehmet ile birlikte Ankara'da ki Nüfus Müdürlüğü'ne, Aziz 
Yıldırım ile birlikte, Şükrü Saraçoğlu Stadı'na gideceğiz."`

Comment: I'm afraid that it didn't work. Btw can you pls help me with my edited question ?

Comment: What is your desired output? You're outputing to string and reading back the string into Tree. I think if we know what's the output you can directly manipulate the Tree object to get it.

Comment: It's above my edit. When it comes to comma it stops and gives me that error. Maybe because str really don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even more inefficient than you realize. You're producing a parse tree, converting it to a string, wrapping it as if it's multiple trees (it isn't), then parsing the wrapped string back into a tree. As soon as you have the parse tree `result`, stop and just remove the POS tags.

An nltk tree is a kind of list, so just iterate over the branches of your tree and remove the POS tag from the leaf tuples. To get your desired format, you also need to add a level of wrapping around words that are not NPs:

```
...
>>> result = cp.parse(tagged_text)
>>> terms = []
>>> for e in result:
    if isinstance(e, tuple):
        terms.append([ e[0] ])
    else:
        terms.append([w for w, t in e])
>>> pprint.pprint(terms)
[['Yarın'],
 [','],
 ['Mehmet'],
 ['ile'],
 ['birlikte'],
 ["Ankara'da", 'ki', 'Nüfus', "Müdürlüğü'ne"],
 [','],
 ['Aziz', 'Yıldırım'],
 ...
```

Comment: I wonder how many time you've heard "worked like a charm !". This exactly i want. I should put  more work to understand the structure Thank you @alexis

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(tree)):
    try:
        arr.append(nltk.Tree.fromstring(str(tree[i]), read_leaf=lambda x: x.split("/")[0]).leaves())
        print(arr[i])
    except ValueError:
        arr.append(tree[i])
        print(arr[i])
```

Isn't efficient but gives my desired output.